# Why is this access denied by SELinux

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

I have a unix socket daemon in my audio HAL, which I need to connect to from my app.

I get SELinux denied log as follows:

```
08-08 10:38:01.939 2622-2622/com.xxx.xxx.xxx W/ksetsdk.xxx: type=1400 audit(0.0:511): avc: denied { connectto } for path=0023xxx scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:r:audioserver:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
```

This is printed even though my app is signed with platform key, is installed in system.img and runs as system:

```
root@hikey:/ # ps | grep xxx                                                                                                                                                                   
system    2619  1893  1561788 86956 SyS_epoll_ 0000000000 S com.xxx.xxx.xxx
root@hikey:/ # ps -Z | grep xxx                                                                                                                                                                
u:r:system_app:s0              system    2619  1893  1561788 86736 SyS_epoll_ 0000000000 S com.xxx.xxx.xxx
root@hikey:/ #
```

And I have added SEPolicy as follows:

```
auditallow system_app audioserver:unix_stream_socket { ioctl read getattr write setattr lock append bind connect getopt setopt shutdown connectto };
```

Can anyone guide me on what I missed? Is there any rule in AOSP SEPolicy that contradicts with this one? How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

There must've been some sync issue in my building aosp and changing SEPolicy rules.

I did more exhaustive testing and found:

(1) When app is signed by platform key, and requests system uid in manifest, it runs as system_app and following rule works:

```
auditallow system_app audioserver:unix_stream_socket { connectto };
```

(2) When app is signed by platform key, but doesn't request system uid in manifest, it runs as platform_app but following rule **doesn't** work:

```
auditallow platform_app audioserver:unix_stream_socket { connectto };
```

(3) If App is not signed by platform key, it runs as priv_app, and following rule **doesn't** work:

```
auditallow priv_app audioserver:unix_stream_socket { connectto };
```

I must've mixed up what rule was built into AOSP when I tested it.

It is still a mystery to me why priv_app or platform_app won't work, but system_app would with similar rule.